# What part of speech does "fledgling" have in the following sentence?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, parts-of-speech, gre

*"Murray has years of experience in family practice, but he is just a fledgling in surgery."*

In the above sentence, is fledgling a noun or an adjective? Or, is it both? Is that why both noun and adjective definitions are present in the following Magoosh practice link?

https://gre.magoosh.com/flashcards/vocabulary/basic-words-3/fledgling

Please provide references for your answer, if possible.

P.s. My punctuation needs work. If you notice any punctuation or grammar problems in my question, please say so!

Comment: It's a noun....

Comment: It's an incipient noun - a fledgling on the verge of flying into full nouniness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, we don't *normally* use article-adjective without a noun to modify (exceptions include uses like *the poor*, as noted below in the comment), so this is an article-noun structure. Let's take it out of context:

> He is a **fledgling**.

Now, try it with an adjective:

> He is a **curious**.

Not so good. Now, with a noun:

> He is a **carpenter**.

That works. In your sentence, fledgling is used as a noun. To reword it as an adjective, we might say:

> He is a **fledgling** ***surgeon***.

But that was not your example.

See [grammerly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adjective/) and [grammarbook](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/adjAdv.asp) for adjective use instruction. And your punctuation looks good.

Comment: +1 However, that's not quite true. We find adjectives functioning as fused modifier heads in phrases such as *the poor* and *the disabled*, for example.

Comment: ...although both the [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/poor) and [Oxford Learner's](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/poor) dictionaries indicate that poor can also be a noun, and the [Oxford](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/disabled) also shows disabled as a noun.

Comment: Ah, but we should [never use dictionaries for parts of speech!](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635)